# Manually editing BizTalk wcf-adapter schema

Tags: xml, wcf, xsd, biztalk

I am new to generating schemas in the way I am doing it now (Manually) and sort of need some help here please. I have a schema, as below, that I am not sure is even correct. What I want is a Customer record that can contain more than one Address record. What I have below does not seem correct, or is it? I am referring in particular to where I have the MAXOCCURS=UNBOUNDED applied. How do you think I ought to do this instead? Thanks in advance

**

```
<xs:element name="Customer">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="CustomerCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Active" type="xs:int" /> 
  <xs:element name="SubNumber" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="CustomerAccountNumber" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="AccountBranchCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="BranchLocationCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Attention" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Addresses">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Street1" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Street2" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PhoneNumbers">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="PhoneNumber" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="PhoneType" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there looks correct, although I would rename the 'Addresses' and 'PhoneNumbers' elements to 'Address' and 'PhoneNumber' respectively. This would imply XML like the following:

```
<Customer>
    <CustomerCode>1234</CustomerCode>
    <Name>Customer</Name>
    ...
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
    <Address>
        ...
    </Address>
    <PhoneNumber>
        ...
    </PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber>
        ...
    </PhoneNumber>
</Customer>
```

Alternatively, you may want to wrap your repeating Address and PhoneNumber elements in Addresses and PhoneNumbers - this often makes life easier if you're attempting to map to WCF DataContracts:

```
  <xs:element name="Addresses">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Street1" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Street2" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

This will give you something like:

```
<Customer>
    <CustomerCode>1234</CustomerCode>
    <Name>Customer</Name>
    ...
    <Addresses>
        <Address>
            ...
        </Address>
        <Address>
            ...
        </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <PhoneNumbers>
        <PhoneNumber>
            ...
        </PhoneNumber>
        <PhoneNumber>
            ...
        </PhoneNumber>
    </PhoneNumbers>
</Customer>
```